# vb.net - remove border from tabcontrol / edit control template

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I'm trying to figure out how to remove a border from a tab control. The closest thing I can find is the following link but I don't know how to add this to my vb.net form.

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=475481

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are you using winforms or WPF?  The link you provided is WPF.

Comment: I'm using winforms, still a bit new to vb.net so I don't understand much :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Have you tried setting the Appearance to Buttons or Flat Buttons?  That may give you the look you're going for.

Comment: Setting the appearance to flat buttons did solve the issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Posting as an answer so you can complete this one)

Try setting the Appearance to Buttons or FlatButtons and see if that gives you the look you want.